# SQLAlchemy autoincrement

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have created a table using using SQLAlchemy. The column `'id'` is set as the primary key and `autoincrement=True` is set for that column. The underlying DB is SQLite.
When I inserting the rows using SQLAlchemy with my python program, I can see that id is getting auto-incremented correctly. However on checking the table schema from the SQLite terminal I can see that column does not have `AUTOINCREMENT` property.

The model schema is as below.

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = Column(Integer(), primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    username = Column(String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)
    name=Column(String(50), nullable=True)
    email = Column(String(40), unique=True, nullable=False)
    created_at = Column(DateTime(), default=datetime.utcnow)
```

The schema output from sqlite terminal:

```
sqlite> .schema users
CREATE TABLE users (
        id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
        username VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, 
        name VARCHAR(50), 
        email VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL, 
        created_at DATETIME, 
        PRIMARY KEY (id), 
        UNIQUE (username), 
        UNIQUE (email)
);
```

Comment: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/sqlite.html#sqlite-auto-incrementing-behavior